# Double subscript caused error during compilation

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have in code:

```
  $\varphi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^ra_k\mathds{1}_{B_k}(x) $
```

but pdflatex commmand generates often:

```
  ? 
  ! Undefined control sequence.
  l.1354 ...rc \xi)(\omega) = \sum_{k=1}^ra_k\mathds
                                              {1}_{B_k}(\xi(\omega))
```

I don't know how to repair this error. It often displays because I use `\mathds{1}` for indicator function. How to fix it ?

Edit:

`\mathds{}` comes from `\usepackage{dsfont}`

Edit: Below is my class

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=2cm, marginparwidth=2.5cm, marginparsep=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex, linkbordercolor={0 0.9 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{marginnote}


\pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\sffamily \nouppercase{\leftmark}}


 % indicator function
 \usepackage{dsfont} 
 \DeclareMathOperator{\1}{\mathds{1}}

 \begin{document}
    $\varphi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^ra_k\mathds{1}_{B_k}(x) $
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The error is nothing to do with the title: have you actually defined `\mathds` somewhere? A minimal working example would of course be helpful

Comment: Since the problem is not the lack of `dsfont`, PLEASE add a MWE

Comment: With the example as given, I get `! LaTeX Error: Command `\lll' already defined.` but not anything about `\mathds`.

Comment: I got '! LaTeX Error: File `dsfont.sty' not found.'. How  to load a missing package ?

Comment: Note that you can not load `amssymb` when using `polish` option of `babel` since the latter defines a `\lll` command in text mode. This is the error mentioned by @JosephWright.

Comment: This `\let\lll\undefined` solved conflict between `babel` and `amssymb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the LaTeX package `dsfont.sty` with the means of your TeX distribution:

- TeX Live package name: `doublestroke`
- MiKTeX package name: `dstroke`

Comment: In fedora: 'sudo yum install doublestroke'

Answer (score 3):

If you press 'h' as response to the error message,

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1354 ...rc \xi)(\omega) = \sum_{k=1}^ra_k\mathds
                                                  {1}_{B_k}(\xi(\omega))
```

you will get the following help text:

```
? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The control sequence at the end of the line is `\mathds`, which is defined by package `dsfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
$\varphi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^ra_k\mathds{1}_{B_k}(x) $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It seems he has loaded it...

Comment: @karlkoeller: The edited question shows, that he knows, where `\mathds` is defined, but he might have forgotten to load the package. Otherwise the OP should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).